# How to draw a pane with rounded corners?

Tags: output-formatting

```
Pane[
 Style["text is here", Bold, FontColor -> Darker[Gray, .6],
  Background -> Red
  ],
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to let the pane have rounded corners?

Comment: Have you tried Framed instead with RoundingRadius?

Comment: Perhaps, you want a `Panel`?

Comment: The following works:

    `Framed[Pane[
      Style["XXXX", FontSize -> 11], 
      ImageMargins -> 1, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
     Background -> Pink, RoundingRadius -> 10, FrameStyle -> None]`


Is `ImageMargins -> 1` there?

Is there a way to get the spaces above and below text narrower?

Comment: FrameMargins -> 0

Comment: @Problemania If I take the last two words of your original question (rounded corners) and type those in the search bar in Mathematica's doc center the first result is `RoundingRadius` and the third `Framed`. Similarly, your question in your comment above can be answered by studying the options of `Framed` in the doc page. `ImageMargins -> -4` and `ContentPadding -> False` will do. Before posting future questions please try to do somewhat more research yourself first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments that are answers should be posted as such.

```
Framed[
  Pane @ Style["text is here", Bold, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.2]],
  Background -> Red,
  RoundingRadius -> 10,
  FrameStyle -> None,
  FrameMargins -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How does _"Comments that are answers should be posted as such."_ explain the answer? ;)

Comment: I couldn't.  I didn't have enough points.

Comment: @Problemania I am sorry, I forget the particular limitations of a new account.  Was the message that you could not answer your own question for two days?  If so, feel free to post your own answer, and I will delete mine.